# Is there Oracle RecordType equivalence in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am converting a Oracle Package to PostgreSQL stored procedure. The Oracle package has "Record" Type in it, is there any equivalence in PostgreSQL for "Record" Type in PostgreSQL?

Here is the code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY LODAXR_TICP_O_pkg02
IS
   g_chnl_key NUMBER := 0;
   g_crrnt_user           VARCHAR2(50);
   TYPE g_entity_dtl_rec IS RECORD
   (
        entity_id                      VARCHAR2(5 CHAR),
        bank_id                     VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),
        branch_id                      VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
        lob_cd                      VARCHAR2(15 CHAR),
        acct_num                    VARCHAR2(15 CHAR),
  )
 g_rec_01 g_entity_dtl_rec;
....
....
```

Comment: Without showing us how you use that "record type", this is impossible to answer. Most likely you can simply use a table's type or create one using [create type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html)

Comment: Postgres has "records" as well. Whether they do the same thing as in Oracle, or whether they do what you need them to do, we can't tell, since you haven't shown us how (and for what) you are using record types in Oracle.

Comment: Could you please put your code in the original question instead of a comment?